# How to resolve Angularjs TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I am using angualrjs and when i launch my app, i am getting the error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

Here is the my code  :

```
   app.config([ '$routeProvider','$locationProvider', '$httpProvider', function($routeProvider, $httpProvider,$locationProvider) {


    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q, $rootScope, $location) {
            return {
                'responseError': function(rejection) {
                    var status = rejection.status;
                    var config = rejection.config;
                    var method = config.method;
                    var url = config.url;

                    if (status == 401) {
                        $location.path( "/login" );
                    } else {
                        $rootScope.error = method + " on " + url + " failed with status " + status;
                    }

                    return $q.reject(rejection);
                }
            };
        });


    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q, $rootScope, $location) {
        return {
            'request': function(config) {
                if (angular.isDefined($rootScope.authToken)) {
                    var authToken = $rootScope.authToken;
                        config.headers['X-Auth-Token'] = authToken;
                    }
                return config || $q.when(config);
            }
        };
    }
);

}]);
```

I don't understand why i have this error

Comment: It means it cannot resolve `$httpProvider.interceptors`. That is, at the time of execution, `$httpProvider.interceptors` is probably `null`, or `undefined`. Is this script executing at the right time (after angular is loaded)?

Comment: What to do to control at what time to execute this code?

Comment: You both helped me. But i can juts accept one answer. Yes,now i remember why the order of parameter is important ( concerning minification)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of your injections is wrong. You put the `$locationProvider` before the `$httpProvider` in the array, so you need the same order within the parameters:

```
app.config([ '$routeProvider','$locationProvider', '$httpProvider', 
function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {});
```

Answer (score 3):

You are probably injecting wrong object instead of `$httpProvider`. Your configuration should look like this:

```
app.config(["$httpProvider", function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myInterceptor');
}]);
```

UPD: You have a typo, just change your

```
app.config([ '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider', function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider)
```

to

```
app.config([ '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider)
```

(just swap `$httpProvider` and `$locationProvider`).